# Keep your code readable with smart indenting : Latex

Tags: editors, overleaf

Is there a way to automatically indent a math environment ? By that, I mean a clean set of equations for the writer and this has absolutely no influence on the output pdf. It is just to make readable the text file. In Matlab, ctr+i is doing this smart indenting. I am wondering if there is an equivalent to that in Latex.

*Update:*
By **smart indenting**, I mean if for instance you have

```
\begin{equation}
\centering
\begin{aligned}
    \begin{dcases}
       \textsf{}  \\
       \textsf{} \\
    \end{dcases}\\
    &{\hspace{}  \textsf{}}
        \end{aligned}
    {\hspace{}  \text{} \hspace{}}
    \begin{aligned}
        \begin{dcases}
       \textsf{}  \\
        \textsf{} \\
    \end{dcases}\\
&{\hspace{}  \textsf{}
        \end{aligned}

\end{equation}
```

the set of lines are correctly tabbed **with respect to each other**. I don't want to indent them all. I want the indent be such that as the code is clean and you can see the nested part of it.

Comment: Uhm, that's an editor issue, not quite a `TeX` issue. And the tag `amsmath` is definitely misleading here.

Comment: This depends on your text editor. I am pretty sure those things exist for Sublime or Atom and other common software.

Comment: Isn't there a common command for all editors ? Or one working with Overleaf ?

Comment: there can not be a common command for all editors: keybindings and functions are highly editor specific . perhaps edit to just ask about overleaf?

Comment: By the way, Ctl-i is also known as Tab.

Comment: I think overleaf basically uses the ACE editor, for which the default keybindings are https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/wiki/Default-Keyboard-Shortcuts

Comment: Hi there! Tom from Overleaf Support here. David is right that Overleaf uses ACE, however, that's not the most relevant point here :) Overleaf does not implement any pretify code option. One of the reasons is that it's very difficult to say which whitespace does modify the output and which doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

the perl script *latexindent* allows to indent the LaTeX code, but it must be started by a command. It can be ordered automatically if your editor allows you to create one. Here is what it returns on your code:

```
\begin{equation}
        \centering
        \begin{aligned}
                \begin{dcases}
                        \textsf{} \\
                        \textsf{} \\
                \end{dcases} \\
                 & {\hspace{}  \textsf{}}
        \end{aligned}
        {\hspace{}  \text{} \hspace{}}
        \begin{aligned}
                \begin{dcases}
                        \textsf{} \\
                        \textsf{} \\
                \end{dcases} \\
                 & {\hspace{}  \textsf{}
        \end{aligned}

\end{equation}
```

Comment: Could you please tell what is the command ? Because, the result that you show here is exactly what I need.

Comment: And this command is only working for some editors and not all of them ? (because @yo' said there is no such a thing in overleaf).

Comment: I am a AUCTeX / Emacs user. Assuming the point in equation environment: C-c . (LaTeX-mark-environment) then C-u M- | latexindent RET (shell-command-on-region) C-u is for replacing the region with the output of the command latexindent. This works only in Emacs, I don'thik universal commands exists.

Comment: @user790082 `latexindent.pl myfile.tex` see the documentation for more details: https://anorien.csc.warwick.ac.uk/mirrors/CTAN/support/latexindent/documentation/latexindent.pdf

Comment: I added a command to AUCTeX to deal with latexindent :         (add-to-list 'TeX-command-list
                       '("Latex Indent" "latexindent -w -s %a"
                         TeX-run-command nil t
                         :help "Run Latexindent on file."))